# std::array finding max value function

Tags: c++, arrays, max

here is my array

```
std::array<double, 64> fm_sim;
```

I want to find the maximum value in the array.

I can't use

```
double maxFmSim = std::max(fm_sim.begin(), fm_sim.end());
```

this is the error :*expected an identifier*

for now this is what I'm doing

```
 double maxFmSim = fm_sim[0];
 for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
 {
    if(fm_sim[i] > maxFmSim)
    {
        maxFmSim = fm_sim[i];
     }
 }
```

Is there a faster way/ other std/stl function which I can use in order to find the max value ?

Comment: Whoops! You forgot to _read the documentation_. cppreference lists all the algorithms you can use. You just need to _read it_.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I forgot to read it again.... yea

Comment: now I can't delete the question ... lol

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The function [`std::max`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) returns the greater value between two values. For a container you can use [`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element). Since this returns an iterator to the max element, you need to dereference it.

```
double maxFmSim = *std::max_element(fm_sim.begin(), fm_sim.end());
```

Comment: thanks that was stupid I didn't remember that function exists

Comment: No need to remember when you can simply look up the list of standard algorithms available.